# Is it possible to overlay dynamic boxes over a live video feed in matlab?

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I'm doing an object recognition project and would like to actively see objects being recognized in a video feed. This requires the object be boxed around in the live feed. The box would automatically adjust in size depending on the size of the object.

Is this possible in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can do it for an image, just do it for every image and you have done it for the video.

If this is too slow, you may only want to calculate the box for every nth image.

In case you want a more detailed answer, please show where you get stuck.